# Suppress repeated messages to SQL Destination, in syslog-ng

Tags: logging, syslog, syslog-ng

I am designing a centralize syslog server, to receive logs from different device, and write them to MySQL. While there are too many repeated messages, I am trying to find a solution.

I found syslog-ng >= 2.1 has added support for suppressing duplicate messages ([Change log](https://czanik.blogs.balabit.com/2012/02/whats-new-in-syslog-ng-3-x/)). But it seems can't work with SQL destination?

I can find suppress option in file destination ([file-destination-doc](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/reference_destination_file.html#supress))
, but in SQL destination, I can't find this option ([sql-destination-doc](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/reference_destination_sql.html))

Is there any way to suppress repeated messages, to SQL destination in syslog-ng  ?

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately, the SQL destnation doesn't support suppressing messages at the moment.

I'd recommend opening an issue ticket for the developers at https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng/issues

As a very ugly workaround, you could make a loop within syslog-ng: send your logs via TCP (with suppress() set) to the same sysog-ng instance, and then send these messages to SQL.

HTH,

Robert